# Ansible with Packer

Tags: ansible, packer

I am trying to get packers ansible provisioner to use a username and password but the configuration with ansible keeps stalling because the authentication step fails.

Here is my Packer Ansible provisioner script.

```
    {
  "type": "ansible",
  "user": "pi",
  "playbook_file": "playbook.yml",
  "extra_arguments": [
    "--extra-vars",
    "ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3",

    "--extra-vars",
    "ansible_user=pi",

    "--extra-vars",
    "ansible_ssh_pass=raspberry",

    "-vvv"
  ]
}
```

I'm a t a complete loss why this does not work.

The output where it gets stuck is as follows.

```
    armpi: ==> arm-image: Executing Ansible: ansible-playbook --extra-vars packer_build_name=arm-image packer_builder_type=arm-image -i /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible288108417 playbook.yml -e ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/tmp/ansible-key528332842 --extra-vars ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 --extra-vars ansible_ssh_user=pi --extra-vars ansible_ssh_pass=raspberry -vvv
```

looks like it is trying to use a `ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/tmp/ansible-key528332842` but I dont want it to use that I really just want it to log in with username and password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the top of the `ansible` provisioner documentation:

> The ansible Packer provisioner runs Ansible playbooks. It dynamically
>   creates an Ansible inventory file configured to use SSH, runs an SSH
>   server, executes ansible-playbook, and marshals Ansible plays through
>   the SSH server to the machine being provisioned by Packer.
>
> **Note:** Any `remote_user` defined in tasks will be ignored. Packer will
>   always connect with the user given in the json config for this
>   provisioner.

What you are trying to do is not possible with the `ansible` provisioner. But you can achieve the thing you try to do by running ansible with the `shell-local` provisioner.

(To get the IP address of the VM to use in the Ansible inventory you can follow the general patter I sugest in [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/packer-tool/tu8E6RMbX0A/99SUPFtxAwAJ).)